# docker system df and Disk Image Size on Docker Desktop don't match

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am running `docker system df` and I see :

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          8         7         46.61GB   26.4GB (56%)
Containers      7         7         16.58GB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   5         5         2.108GB   0B (0%)
Build Cache     26        3         3.133kB   0B
```

So, that adds up to ~74GB. But on my Mac, if I go
`Docker desktop > Settings Resources > Disk Image Size` I see 112GB used. Where does the rest go?

What commands is Docker desktop using for finding that out?

Comment: Docker Desktop was reporting the Linux VM’s disk usage, plus swap I think. But must have been buggy because I upgraded my client today and the spaced used is gone and the disk usage plugin is being promoted in the UI.

Comment: I think docker desktop has changed significantly, so if you still would like an answer, you'd need to include the version of docker desktop that you were/are running that still had those options as you have given in order to reproduce and follow up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker system df` shows Docker daemon disk usage, but Docker Desktop uses a [VM under the hood](https://www.docker.com/blog/the-magic-behind-the-scenes-of-docker-desktop/). What you see is probably the VM Disk size VS. Docker daemon files which may differ: the diff may be **non-Docker files in Docker Desktop VM** (though the diff seems important)

Note: Docker for Mac 4.7.0 uses [HyperKit](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit), it may change depending on versions and OS

It may also be related to a potential [Docker disk space leaks tracked by #1432](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1423) or the way disk size is computed for VM differing from disk size computed by `docker system df`